# Cannon uninstall pip3, but pip3 --version shows it is existing

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I installed conda and pip, also i have pip3. I installed jupyter notebook with pip, but when i started with jupyter notebook, i didnt have some packages, so i decided to uninstall pip and use jupyter from conda, because jupyter and terminal command 'python' didn't see some packages, that did have conda

i used:
pip uninstall pip

but nothing changes, 'python' and jupyter notebook is still working as he worked before
i tried to do pip3 uninstall pip3, but it says "Cannot uninstall requirement pip3, not installed"

Help me, please, how do i delete pip at all from Linux Mint?

pip3 --version shows "pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)"

pip3 list also works

Maybe question is really stupid, but i`m new to programming, so i really don't understand, how it works, so hoping to your understanding.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `pip3 uninstall pip`? `pip3` is the version-specific alias to manage Python 3 packages, but `pip` is the package name on all versions of Python. It's also possible it's installed via the OS package manager, so you may want to do `sudo apt-get remove python3-pip` or something to that effect.

Comment: why do you waste time for this?

Comment: if you don't need `jupyter` then uninstall `jupyter`, not `pip`

Comment: problem has been solved, thanks to all

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall pip
```

if you are using python3-pip

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python3-pip
```